# How to correct fs size for logical volume

Tags: lvm, resize2fs

I decreased logical volume `lv_postgres` size for a 5G. then redistributed free space to other lv `lv_home`, but didn't do resize2fs for the decreased volume `lv_postgres'`. At the next boot i fall into emergence mode and `resize2fs lv_postgres` dont't do the task saying "Please run `e2fsck -f`" and the last one say "Either the superblock or pt is likely to be corrupt" if i continue then on pass 5 get "error reading block while reading inode and block bitmaps"
the fs size according to superblock is 2564096 blocks
the physical size of device is 1253376 blocks
i want to reduce volume from 9.78G to 4.78G to match required size

Which is a right way to correct size for volume?

Comment: An additional Q is why system start only in emergency mode? i don't have an option to start normal mode?

Comment: If the system starts only in emergency mode, it means it has detected some _serious_ inconsistency, that requires manual repair before continuing. Most probably the truncated/mangled volume. The data there is probably lost forever.

Answer (score 2):

If you shrinked your LV without shrinking your filesystem first, it's corrupt and the data on it is lost, since files were likely stored in the now longer accessible areas. Filesystems do not like this at all and you may not be able to repair it.

If you didn't write any data yet to the other LV which now occupies the space, your best bet is to restore the original LV layout (you may be able to find suitable backups in /etc/lvm/*/), undoing the LV resizes. If nothing was written the filesystem may still be intact and you can recover from there.

If you already grew the other filesystem to the same area, you'll just repeat The same problems with the home partitions.

Answer (score 0):

i am not an expert but let me see whether i can help you. you had a logical volume lg1 and reduced it to 4.7G but did not run `resize2fs` before creating another logical volume lg2 from the freed space.

I believe you do not have any data on lg2.

Why cannot you

- Delete logical volume lg2
- Run `resize2fs` on lg1
- Recreate lg2

Comment: i added a space to lv_home which (lv1) is almost full of data, so i don't want delete it.